# PowerShell Get-ADUser with ANR

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-5.1

I'm trying to search Active Directory for a user with the following statement, but I get an error when I use $("smtp:$user").

`get-aduser -filter {(anr -eq $user) -or (anr -eq $("smtp:$user"))}`

Could anyone explain why please, or is there a better way of achieving the same result. I would like user to be able to contain, Name, email or SAM information, and use the same code to search.

*get-aduser : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is not valid. Change the value of the "path" argument and run the operation again.*
*At line:1 char:1*.
*get-aduser -filter {(anr -eq $user) -or (anr -eq $("smtp:$user"))}

CategoryInfo:NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], PSArgumentException

FullyQualifiedErrorId:ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser*

Comment: "I get an error when I use $("smtp:$user")." - Looks like you forgot to post the error message :)

Comment: You could try the LDAPFilter: `Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(|(anr=$user)(anr=$("smtp:$user")))"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, as the first condition will include anything in the second condition.

Does this look better?:

```
$user = "SmithJ"
$SMTP = "smtp:$user"

Get-ADUser -Filter {anr -eq $user -or anr -eq $SMTP}
```

Comment: Hi Judd,
When I have tried this on my system,
`Get-ADUser -Filter {anr -eq "john.smith"}`
returns no results, but
`Get-ADUser -Filter {anr -eq "smtp:john.smith"}`
does, which is where the original code came from.
I also managed to get it to work as expected by creating the $SMTP variable first, but I couldn't see why I needed to.....

Comment: what is the format of the "Samaccountname", the "userprincipalname" and the "email address"?

Comment: SAM: 123456
upn: john.smith@
email:john.smith@

Comment: Im sorry, but i cannot replicate the issues. ARN will search the UPN for "*john.smith*" and the proxyAddresses for "*John.smith*".

Comment: At the bottom of this article, it shows you how to enable ANR on other attributes. Looks like its not enabled on UPN by default. (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22653.active-directory-ambiguous-name-resolution.aspx)

Comment: `-Filter` should be a **string** not a scriptblock: `Get-ADUser -Filter "anr -eq '$user' -or anr -eq '$smtp'"`